# Split arrays into unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'm having a simple issue I can't seem to fix. Below is a simplified version:

```
var data = {
    Alabama: ['AL 1', 'AL 2', 'AL 3'],
    Alaska: ['AK 1', 'AK 2', 'AK 3'],
}
```

Is being printed using `data.Alabama`, `data.Alaska`, etc.

The unformatted return is: *AL 1,AL 2,AL 3* (comma-separated, no space).

The basic issue I'm running into is splitting the array with a line break or something similar. jQuery is acceptable and I've tried some basic methods with regex and slice, but nothing seems to return what I'm looking for. The only restriction is that the call to `data.Alabama` must remain the same (i.e. `data.Alabama[0]`, `data.Alabama[1]` is not acceptable).

Ultimately my desired output would be an unordered list of the array, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>AL 1</li>
    <li>AL 2</li>
    <li>AL 3</li>
</ul>
```

but just using line breaks would be acceptable also:

```
AL 1<br/>
AL 2<br/>
AL 3<br/>
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: could you do data.Alabama.join("<br />"); then inject this into the dom

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard can't believe I totally forgot about .join(). That's the perfect approach for the line break solution, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're confident the data will never contain characters needing HTML escapes, something like:

```
var alabama = "<ul><li>" +
  data.Alabama.join("</li><li>") +
  "</li></ul>";
```

would do it.

```js
var data = {
    Alabama: ['AL 1', 'AL 2', 'AL 3'],
    Alaska: ['AK 1', 'AK 2', 'AK 3'],
};

document.getElementById('ctr').innerHTML = 
  "<ul><li>" +
  data.Alabama.join("</li><li>") +
  "</li></ul>";
```

```html
<div id="ctr">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `map` and `join`:

```
var output = ["<ul>",data.Alabama.map(function(str){
    return '\t<li>'+str+'</li>'
  }).join('\n'),"</ul>"].join("\n")

console.log(output)
```

Prints out:

```
<ul>
    <li>AL 1</li>
    <li>AL 2</li>
    <li>AL 3</li>
</ul>
```